# How to change post thumbnail title and alt attributes to post title?

Tags: theme-development, functions, post-thumbnails

Can we change the title and alt attributes of the_post_thumbnails and set them to post title instead ? like creating a function for it and adding a filter ? I tried searching but I can't seem to find what I want.

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

second argument in this function you can set a few set fields, such as alt, title, source and class:

```
$default_attr = array(
        'src'   => $src,
        'class' => "attachment-$size",
        'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( wp_postmeta->_wp_attachment_image_alt )),
        'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$title_attribute = the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
the_post_thumbnail(
    'full', 
    array(
        'alt'   => $title_attribute, 
        'title' => $title_attribute 
    )
);
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: i've need in some website so i've tried below code its not work sometimes or may my coding mistake or so i've tried above my code and its work fine...
but may i know why you are asking about it...?

Comment: " but may i know why you are asking about it...? "... because answers should be explanations not raw code dumps.